# OctoberCMS - Rainlab translate

Tags: localization, octobercms, translate

I am looking for a way to set the default locale for certain host servers.

Given the servername is server-spain, e.g. I would like to redirect by default to the spanish translation, preferably any page the user lands, besides browser settings. So by default, even the app language/locale is English by default, if accessing through website.es (spanish domain) the user will see spanish as default language.

```
$this['servername'] = gethostname(); // host name
{% if servername is same as('server-in-spain') %}
// reload with spanish locale
{% endif %}
```

Anybody found themselves in this situation? Anybody solved it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code to your `layout's code section` and it should do the job.

```php
use RainLab\Translate\Classes\Translator;

public function onStart() {
    
    $translator = Translator::instance();
    $currentLocale = $translator->getLocale();
    $newLocale = 'es';
    $translatedRedirect = false;
    $servername = gethostname(); // <- YOUR FUNCTION TO FIND HOST
    
    // MAKE SURE IF YOU DO NOT HAVE GIVEN LOCAE IN Backend
    // THNE IT WILL REDIRECT TO DEFAULT SET LOCALE
    if($servername === 'server-in-spain') {
        $newLocale = 'es';        
                
    }
    if($servername === 'server-in-germany') {
        $newLocale = 'de';    
    }
    
    // we do not want to redirect if user have already perfect locale
    if($currentLocale !== $newLocale) {
        $translatedRedirect = true;
    }
    
    if($translatedRedirect) {
        
        $translator->setLocale($newLocale);
        $currentUrl = $this->currentPageUrl();
        
        $parts = parse_url($currentUrl);
        $path = array_get($parts, 'path');
        
        $pageUrl = http_build_url($parts, [
            'path' => '/' . $translator->getPathInLocale($path, $newLocale)
        ]);

        return Redirect::to($pageUrl);
    }    
}
```

[image]

It should do the job

if any doubt please comment

Comment: Many thanks, Hardik, works like a charm! 
The last item now will be to solve the adding of /es after the .es which is still showing even being set up with the extended locale settings. I guess it is because it is forced here.

Comment: glade it worked for you, if you share your issue with some example I can help you to solve :)

Answer (score 1):

With Hardik's answer I could solve it.
The only issues I encountered with this solution were :

1. I wasnt able to select a different locale in a given domain. That is example.es , correctly displaying /es locale but unable to switch locales (as it was forced by the code)

I solved it with a first time cookie:

```
function onStart() {
        //Set the cookie for firt time visit
        $first_visit = !isset( $_COOKIE["fist_locale"] );

        // Set the cookie so that the message doesn't show again
        setcookie( "first_locale", 1, strtotime( '+1 week' ) );
        if( $first_visit ){ // if user first time
        
            $translator = Translator::instance();
                $currentLocale = $translator->getLocale();
                $newLocale = 'en';
                $translatedRedirect = false;
                $servername = gethostname(); // <- YOUR FUNCTION TO FIND HOST
                
                // MAKE SURE IF YOU DO NOT HAVE GIVEN LOCAE IN Backend
                // THNE IT WILL REDIRECT TO DEFAULT SET LOCALE
                if($servername === 'example.es') {
                    $newLocale = 'es';        
                            
                }
                if($servername === 'example.de') {
                    $newLocale = 'de';    
                }
              
                
                // we do not want to redirect if user have already perfect locale
                if($currentLocale !== $newLocale) {
                    $translatedRedirect = true;
                }
                
                if($translatedRedirect) {
                    
                    $translator->setLocale($newLocale);
                    $currentUrl = $this->currentPageUrl();
                    
                    $parts = parse_url($currentUrl);
                    $path = array_get($parts, 'path');
                    
                    $pageUrl = http_build_url($parts, [
                        'path' => '/' . $translator->getPathInLocale($path, $newLocale)
                    ]);
            
                    return Redirect::to($pageUrl);
                }    
            
            }//end of first time
}
```

2. The locale forced by the domain name function adds /(locale) after the domain as in example.de/de